# New Zealand Immigration query on third-party checks after JSV?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, new-zealand

I am presently living and working in New Zealand. I applied for a Skilled Migrant Category Residence visa, but they only offered JSV, since I don’t have a job offer. Below is my timeline:

1. Lodgment date: 27 July 2019
2. 1st CO contact: May 2022
3. JSV form sent: October 2022
4. JSV approved: Feb 2023
5. NZ arrival: April 2023
6. Landed in Job: July 2023
7. Job offer and INZ 1235 form sent on 5th July 2023
8. New CO contacted to file INZ 1200 form on 24th July 2023
9. Requested more documents on 31st July 2023

I am a bit confused and worried since the CO said that my case has been sent to third-party check (and she confirmed it is not NSC). My job offer is conditional to visa (JSV / work visa) validity and it is only till 2nd Feb 2023. My concerns are:

1. My JSV never mentioned that a third-party check will be done after securing the job.
2. Is a third-party check common for JSV applicants?
3. Will this check be completed before my visa expires?
4. If not, do they provide any bridging visa?

Comment: Can you expand what is JSV?

Comment: JSV means Job Search Visa. You will be offered this visa once your Skilled Migrant category residence documents for NZ is all verified and found you don't have job offer or skilled employment.

Comment: Similar situation here. CO has mentioned they will extend my JSV since it's expiring in next one week. Our Third Party check is waiting for more than six months now. CO mentioned they have contacted Third Party Check for an update. What is your visa status, have you cleared Third party check now? Thanks!